# Issues facing with JBehave

Tags: java, bdd, junit4, jbehave

I have created the story/scenario. like:

```
Scenario:  Create a new Firm 

Given a Firm Test
When Firm Test is valid
Then New Firm Test is Created
```

I have created the Steps class with the following Given , Then annotations like:

```
 @Given("a Firm $FirmName") 
    public void firm(String FirmName)
    {       
    System.out.println("Firm Name : " + FirmName);      
    }

    @When("Firm $FirmName is valid")
    public void validateFirm(String FirmName) {
        //validate the Firm Name and dates
        System.out.println("Firm Name in when: " + FirmName);   
    }
```

And also I have an class in place which takes care of configuration(), candidateSteps() and storyPaths() methods.

Now when run the class a JUnit test class should not it print the two above statements in firm() and validateFirm() methods ?

I get an output with PENDING status for all the scenarios, though I have methods for the same annotations.

Could someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have annotation for "Then" as well. Another point is to check the class you're executing is the embeddable class that extends Junit class, not the steps class.

Answer (score 0):

At my tests the pending status is starting at the second Und (keyword in german) - if i change the word Und in the story file to Wenn so it will be run correctly.